# Videojs doesnt play video from another server in IE10/9/8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

VideoJS plays video in IE10 from local file, but not plays from another place (VZAAR videohosting)

In Console displays: Video Error,[object Object]

Comment: Please provide some further examples and describe the steps you need to reproduce the error as well as giving some hints about the exact versions you use...

Comment: videojs - last version from site. I use ExtJS 4.2 Framework.

Comment: me.autoEl = {
   tag: 'div',
   cn: [{
    id: id,
    tag: 'video',
    cn: [subtitlesArray, videoSourcesArray],
    cls: 'video-js vjs-default-skin',
    preload: 'none',
    controls: 'controls',
    width: 'auto',
    height: '100%'
   }]
  };

Comment: Does it work in any browser? Have you watched your network traffic using Fiddler or F12's Network tab to verify the video is downloading properly?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're using the correct video source URL? For Vzaar hosted videos, the URL will be in the format of:

```
https://view.vzaar.com/{videoID}/video
```

where {videoID} is your video's ID number. You can also find this URL on Vzaar by viewing your videos list and selecting 'manage' for the video you're using. The correct URL is the 'video' URL under 'advanced video links'.

A simple example of working code using the CDN version of VideoJS (replace your own video's ID, height, and width values):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>VideoJS Vzaar playback test</title>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.1/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="testVideo"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls preload="auto"
    width="{videoWidth}" height="{videoHeight}"
    poster="https://view.vzaar.com/{videoID}/image">
    <source src="https://view.vzaar.com/{videoID}/video" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's server problem. Not octet-stream, but video/mp4